# How to prepare string variable format in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass Roll_no to my rest API ?
I want pass Roll_no like this format:

```
String roll_no = '3250$10';
```

How to prepare this format? 
I have add $ between 3250 and 10 but it gives error like Expected an identifier.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear enough. Please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is roll number length is fixed?

Comment: The `$` character in Dart is used for String interpolation. If you want a literal $ you'll need to escape it like: `String Roll_no='3250\$10';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this

```
String Roll_no='3250\$10'
```

Answer (score 26):

If you are attempting to put a String variable inside another static String you can do the following for simple variables:

```
String firstString = 'sentence';
String secondString = 'This is a $firstString';
```

Which will output `This is a sentence`.

If the String is a property of an object, then you must use `${}`like this:

```
person.name = 'Shilpa';
String newString = 'This is my name: ${person.name}';
```

Which will output `This is my name: Shilpa`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a backslash before the $ like this:

```
String Roll_no='3250\$10';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 ways to have $ in a String:

- by escaping it with a backslash: `String Roll_no = '3250\$10';`
- by using a [raw string](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings):  `String Roll_no = r'3250$10';`