# how to show a varibal in text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make the dollar sign recognize the   snapshot.data[i]['name']   But she only gets to know snapshot
plz help me `DropdownSearch(items: [ for (i=0 ; i < 10; i++) "$snapshot.data[i]['name']", ])`

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: answer to these type issue is already available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prepare string variable format in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682797/how-to-prepare-string-variable-format-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

I am writing what I understand from your question

```
"${snapshot.data[i]['name']"}, ]
```

Comment: Yes and thanks, that's what I want